# Can we have a list of users by votes cast?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

On the users tab, we can currently see a list of users that we can view in four ways by clicking one of four tabs:

- Reputation
- Newest
- Oldest
- Name

It would be great to see a fifth tab that allowed us to see users sorted by the number of votes they have cast.

This would encourage users to vote more often, which would help with adoption on new sites and getting the better questions and answers to float to the top.

The number of votes cast is, in a lot of ways, just as important as the number of votes received, because you can't have one without the other. Additionally voting is a great way to participate on more established sites like Stackoverflow that have so many questions and answers that it makes it difficult for new users to add something of value.

We already show this information on each user profile; this request would simply roll it up to the users page to be able to view another level of participation on the sites.

Comment: you are a visionary ahead of your time! see my updated answer :)

Comment: I knew you'd come round to my way of thinking eventually ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<s>What purpose would this serve? I guess I don't see the benefit, and near as I can recall, this is the first time this idea has ever surfaced in two years of operation..</s>

Turns out, we now agree with you. :) mea culpa.

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/redesigned-users-page/

and

https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=voters

Comment: I can't help it if I have great ideas....

Comment: As I mentioned in the comment above, it would encourage people to vote on sites like programmers.se where you believe too many crappy questions are being asked. By introducing a publicly viewable way to see who is participating on a site, you will have the side effect of getting the better questions floating to the top. You say reputation is a measure of how much you participate on a site, but this is another way to do that.

Comment: @paddy problem is this is a "score" you get by clicking a button over and over. rep comes from *other people* voting. Critical difference.

Comment: Do you think this information is more or less useful than the "newest", "oldest" or "name" tabs? Do you think this would encourage more users to use their votes? There's already a daily vote limit, so its not like votes could escalate out of hand and on sites like programmers.se where you currently feel the need to close questions because of their poor quality, you would have more votes cast for the better questions and answers which should help the good questions rise above the poor ones.

Answer (score 1):

The downside:

It would encourage people to vote
   without thinking about it just to be
   higher on the list. There are [already](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/32/civic-duty) [badges](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/54/electorate) for voting anyway. Also, from what I've seen, there isn't even a serious shortage of votes.

Comment: I'm not sure why the absence or presence of badges matters. There are many badges for reputation already, but we list the users by reputation. I think voting should be encouraged, particularly on newer SE sites and there are limits already in place to stop voting being abused.

Comment: @Paddyslacker: Those systems (presumably) can't exactly tell how much thought people put into their votes.

Comment: Maybe a new badge to higher count of casting votes could helps. It's ridiculous to see the relation of votes casted and votes received floating about 1/100. Users need give back what they receive.

Comment: Very true. Thanks for the thoughtful response.